# When did the five have an opportunity to create the skin-jobs?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In BSG it is said that the skin jobs were created by the Final 5. We also know that the skin jobs were created between the last war and the current timeline. However, some of the Final 5 (namely

> Tigh

) are accountable as being "among" humans and therefore not remembering their Cylon nature since before the skin jobs would have been created.

How did

> Tigh create the skin-jobs while he was running around with Adama post-first Cylon War?

Comment: The cylons were experimenting with organic robotics during the first war. I forget which episode covered it, but Adama stumbled upon a laboratory in which the Cylons were researching this.

Comment: true, but it took the Final 5 to give them the secret of their construction.

Comment: @Xantec That was part of the first movie's release: [*BSG: Razor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica:_Razor_Flashbacks).

Comment: Well, the Final 5 gave them resurrection technology. That was what Cavil was negotiating for in the finale, on BSG's bridge, when Tyrol killed Torri.

Comment: Also, more than one copy of a model can be active at once. So while one copy was playing cowboys and indians with Adama, another one could have been helping the cylons.

Comment: Assuming the final five all were placed in human society because of 1's rebellion, that would have placed Tigh's entrance after the creation of the skin-jobs, which seemingly it isn't..

Comment: @Pyrodante Welcome to the wonderful world of ret-cons. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The earliest evidence (that we the viewers have) of Tigh actually being in human society is when he meets Adama for the first time, some time after the Cylon War is over.

It is conceivable that the first skin-jobs were created at the end of the War, and just after, but before that fateful meeting between Tigh and Adama.

Comment: After doing a even more research I have discovered that all of Saul's war memories were implanted, although this brings up another question which I ask here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9731/3958

Answer (score 7):

You've got the timeline wrong.  The Final 5 arrived in Colonial space, and worked with the Cylons late in the first Cylon War.  The skinjobs were created, then the number 1s (i.e. the Cavils) revolted.  They wiped the Final 5's memories and inserted them into human society.

Comment: This is the correct answer.