# How did Cavil manage to sneak the Five into human society?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Cavil must have gone to great lengths to introduce the Five into the human population. You can see some of the effort in The Plan, though that is more to save a Five already in the population. Although the Five are clearly introduced at different times in history (Tigh and Ellen seem to be the earliest), one problem remains:

*How did Cavil fake Tigh's military documents?* If his military history (including his discharge) was a fabricated memory that Cavil implanted, how was Adama able to get him "back in"? Without faked documents, he would have discovered Tigh's true history. *How much access does Cavil really have?*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All of the Final Five would have needed faked records - indeed, all of the cylons that were inserted into colonial society would have needed them.

It isn't inconceivable that the cylons were experts at computer systems, and were able to infiltrate records and replace them. Bribery of administrators and people in useful positions is also not unlikely. Since skin-jobs were not known in the colonies at the time, it would have been easy to make shady deals with people only suspecting typical criminal motives rather than a more sinister cylon plot.

I'd imagine that the colonies would have been a bit of a mess after the Cylon War, and it usually isn't difficulties for new identities to be created in that kind of turmoil (happened after WWII with a number of people adopting new persona after the war).

Answer (score 0):

episode 15 of season 4, refer to Ander's attempt to explain his newly uncovered memories just before being dragged off against his will for a botched brain surgery.

Answer (score 0):

the cavil's wanted to prove a point to the final 5, that humans were flawed and self destructive and didnt deserve a place in the universe and that the cavil's were jealous, angry not being "made" into something more superior than humans. the cavil's put new memories in the final 5 and placed them on the colonies, to go through life with the other humans, after the genocide of the colonies ( the final 5 were suppose to die and resurrect), the cavil's wanted the final 5 to realize how flawed the humans were and be given apologies. things went wrong, being that the final 5 became more human than cylon and all survived the destruction, which wasnt suppose to happen.

Answer (score -1):

The Final Five you are referring to? They created all the other models: Cavil, Simon, Sharon, Six, Dana, Dorel, Leoban (and Daniel). The other 8 models didn't even know who the final Five were. So I highly doubt Cavil had anything to do with them being in Human society. The "Final Five" (who were more correctly the original five) made it pretty clear at the end of the series that they were trying to live - generally - in peace with Humanity, once they remembered who they were. They were trying to avoid the mistakes that had destroyed 'Earth-that-was'.

That's completely different though from the fact that he WAS involved in sneaking in the Sixes, the Sharons, the Simons, the Dorels and Leobans who were in society. That we do see some of in `The Plan`.

Comment: It is stated that the Final 5 were wiped of their memories and sent to live among humans by Cavil to prove a point.

Comment: From the BSG Wiki " Cavil boxed the Five at first but ultimately unboxed them and downloaded them into new bodies, blocking their true memories and implanting false ones, then introducing them one by one into the colonies. "

Comment: +1: getting many cylons in but -1: Cavil did know who the final five were (but this only becomes obvious towards the end of season 4 and in The Plan).

Comment: Wow, okay I stand corrected. I TOTALLY missed that. Is the wiki link on Cavil's page, or the Final Five's? I have to go check that out now.

Comment: Wait, so then he would have had to have scrubbed every Cylon database and the memory of every "living" skin-job, centurion, hybrid and potentially raider then, no? Otherwise surely SOMEONE among the Cylons would've remembered and known who the Final Five were.

Comment: I see *zero* evidence to back this claim up! Where did anyone ever get the idea that Canvil even met the original Five? Where do they get that he deprived them of oxygen and boxed them? Man! Did I miss a few episodes or whaT?

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith Yes, I believe you did...  Cavil put the Five on the colonies to teach them a lesson.  Near the end, he goes on a rant (to, I think, Ellen) and explains everything he did.